# How to pass data to django_tables2's LinkColumn

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

My urlconf snippet is:

```
url(r'^play/(?P<songid>\d+)', 'playid', name="playsongid")
```

the playid is a view function, it's definition like this:

```
def playid(request, songid):
    #do something
```

I use the django-tables2 library, their tutorial is [django-tables2][1].
My table sinppet is:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class TestTable(tables.Table)
    links = tables.LinkColumn("playsongid", kwargs={"songid": ...})
```

the "..." is my confused position. How I pass a variety of `songid` data to it in my view function(this view function isn't `playid`, it's another view function)?
I want the django-tables2 can render data like this:

```
column
<a href="/play/1">aaa</a>
<a href="/play/2">bbb</a>
<a href="/play/3">ccc</a>
```

---

Comment: Now I get it to work! tables.py finally like this:

    `import django_tables2 as tables
    from django_tables2.utils import Accessor
    
    class TestTable(tables.Table)
        links = tables.LinkColumn("playsongid", kwargs={"songid": Accessor("songid")})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I get it to work by myself! tables.py finally like this:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.utils import Accessor

class TestTable(tables.Table)
    songid = tables.Column()
    links = tables.LinkColumn("playsongid", kwargs={"songid": Accessor("songid")})
```

In my view function I pass data to it like this

```
    playlist = conn.playlistinfo()
    table_data = []
    for info in playlist:
        tmp_dict = {"songid": info.id}
        tmp_dict["links"] = "%s - %s" % (get_attr(info, "artist"), get_attr(info, "title"))
        table_data.append(tmp_dict)
        del tmp_dict
    variables["table"] = PlaylistTable(table_data)
```